# WF 4: Define a SendReply activity programmaticaly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to define a SendReply activity on windows workflow foundation 4. I am using the following code

```
           SendReply reply = new SendReply();
        ResponseParameter = new Variable<string>("ResponseParameter");
        reply.Content = new SendParametersContent { Parameters = { "out1", new InArgument<string>(ResonseParameter) } };
```

And i get the following error at this line: ""out1", new InArgument("ResonseParameter")"

The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection>.Add(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`Parameters` is a dictionary, so you need to use a dictionary initializer, not a list initializer. In other words, use *two* sets of curly braces:

```
reply.Content = new SendParametersContent { 
    Parameters = { 
        { "out1", new InArgument<string>(ResonseParameter) } 
    }
};
```